# Phonegap Plugin - append lines to app delegate

Tags: ios, cordova, config, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a phonegap plugin. So far so good.
Now I would like to append 1 or 2 methods to the AppDelegate.m through the config.xml so it will be populated for the developer automatically.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If you find a solution I would love to know how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take a look into the Push Plugin, they use an objective-c category for the appDelegate

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

If you just want to be notified when the app becomes active you don't need to change anything on the AppDelegate, just put this on your plugin:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil]; 

- (void)onAppDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification*)notification
{

     NSLog(@"%@",@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how it works. In the "regular" AppDelegate, will I be notify on app become active and etc.?

Comment: If you just want to be notified when the app becomes active you don't need to change anything on the AppDelegate, just put this on your plugin: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidBecomeActive:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to override some other method, like if iOS doesn't issue a notification for some app delegate method, you can do it with method swizzling. [jcesarmobile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351469/jcesarmobile) mentioned this repo in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22191923/2199492), but a file with an example is:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2Bnotification.m