# Cordova Plugin - append method to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, appdelegate

I'm developing a Cordova plugin. Now I need to append a method to AppDelegate.m through my plugin. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Answer (score -3):

Possibile duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490212/phonegap-plugin-append-lines-to-app-delegate) question.

New plugin's repository link is [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want add method to AppDelegate.m, not overriding it. Do you have any command? Thanks.